# Spring boot + JWT Authorization header is not persisting to provide to subsequent requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I'm developing an application with Spring boot and implemented authentication with JWT. When I test the API with postman I can see it creates the Authorization header and when manually post it to header subsequent rest calls work without any issue. But when I do the rest calls from my JavaFX application, I can see the token created by the login rest call but subsequent rest calls fail with 403 forbidden status code. When I debug, The issue is when the JWTAuthFilter(which was implemented by extending GenericFilterBean) tries to get the Authorization header to pass that to subsequent rest calls, it returns null.

```
String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
```

request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING) always returns null.

```
/**
* WebSecurityConfig
*/
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/rest/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                // We filter the rest/login requests
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/rest/login", authenticationManager()),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                // And filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in header
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthFilter(),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }


/**
* JWTAuthFilter
*/
public class JWTAuthFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Authentication authentication = TokenAuthenticationService.getAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) request);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

/**
* TokenAuthenticationService
*/
public class TokenAuthenticationService {

    static final long EXPIRATIONTIME = 864_000_000; // 10 days
    static final String SECRET = "ThisIsASecret";
    static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer";
    static final String HEADER_STRING = "Authorization";

    static void addAuthentication(HttpServletResponse res, String username) {
        String JWT = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(username)
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATIONTIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET)
                .compact();
        res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + " " + JWT);
    }

    static Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        if (token != null) {
            // parse the token.
            String user = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(SECRET)
                    .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                    .getBody()
                    .getSubject();

            return user != null ?
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, emptyList()) :
                    null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```